# vuejs: v-if directive for event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can I react to an event in a vue template? Say a child component dispatches an event `$dispatch('userAdded')`, could I do something like this in the parent component:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" v-if="userAdded">
    User was created!
</div>
```

or, if not, can I access variables of the child component?

```
<div class="alert alert-info" v-if="$refs.addView.form.successful">
    User was created!
</div>
```

I tried both without success.

Also, while I'm here, is there an expressive way to hide elements after a certain amount of time? Something like (to hide after 2s):

```
<div class="alert alert-info" v-if="$refs.addView.form.successful" hide-after="2000">
    User was created!
</div>
```

Thanks!

**edit:** wrote my own `hide-after` directive:

```
Vue.directive('hide-after', {
  update: function(value) {
    setTimeout(() => this.el.remove(), value);
  }
});

<div class="alert alert-info" v-hide-after="2000">
    This will be shown for 2 seconds
</div>
```

Comment: is `form.successful` part of the data, props or a computed in your `addView` component?

Comment: why dont you just dispatch an event with the info from the child you need?

Comment: @nils: `form.successful` is part of my data in the `addView` component

Comment: @eltonkamami: and then write that info to the parent's `data`? That's what I'm trying to avoid if there's an easier way.

Comment: @Chris as i understand from your code, child handles creation and parent shows success message. you can pass a parent function as a prop to the child and call it upon user creation. either predefine the property to parents `data` or create it with `this.$set` on the fly

Comment: Why did you say that accessing child's data through $refs is not working for you? Works for me fine https://jsfiddle.net/esdhwgme/1/

Comment: @eltonkamami: correct. I'll try passing in a function as a prop!
@AndreyEtumyan: perhaps because you're setting `this.$refs.addview.form.successful = true` in the parent? Or maybe I had another problem. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can but you need to take this approach.

1. Create a child that dispatches an event
2. In the parent component create an event listener for the event and also a data property that the event listener will set locally on the component instance
3. In the parent bind your v-if to the local data component

The code would look something like

**parent**

HTML

```
<div v-if="showAlert"></div>
```

Js

```
events: {
  'alert.show': function () {
    this.showAlert = true
  },
  'alert.hide': function () {
    this.showAlert = false
  }
},
data () {
  return {
    showAlert: false
  }
}
```

**Child**

Js

```
methods: {
  showAlert (show) {
    show ? this.$dispatch('alert.show') : this.$dispatch('alert.hide')
  }
}
```

The reason you should avoid using the $child and $parent is that it makes that component always depend on the fact that the parent will have the alert property and makes the child component lest modular

Since dispatch goes up until it hits a listener you can have several nested components in between the parent and child dispatching the alert control

**UPDATE**

Alternately, since you do not like the LOE of using events you can create a 2-way property on the child that either the parent or child can update

Example

**Parent**

HTML

```
<div v-if="showAlert"></div>
<child-component :show-alert.sync="showAlert"></child-component>
```

JS

```
data () {
  return {
    showAlert: false
  }
}
```

**Child**

js

```
props: {
  showAlert: {
    type: Boolean,
    twoWay: true
  }
},
methods: {
  showAlertInParent (show) {
    this.$set('showAlert', show)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thought of that, was hoping there was a directer way. I'm accepting your answer anyway though :). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Chris - updated answer with an alternative using 2-way props

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of events is that you can react to them. But you want the reaction to pass by the model. You really don't want unrelated bits of markup listening and reacting 'independently'. $dispatch is deprecated. To do this now, do the following...

In the child component, emit an event as follows

```
this.$emit('didIt' {wasItAwful:'yep',wereYouScared:'absolutely'});
```

In the parent, you register the event listener with v-on, as an attribute of the child's tag...

```
<adventure-seeking-child v-on:did-it='myChildDidIt' />
```

Then, in the parent's methods, define your handler.

```
methods : { myChildDidIt : function(payload){ ... } }
```

Docs are [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components).